# Get date (yyyy-mm-dd) from dataframe containing week number, day of the week

Tags: r, date, lubridate

Spent 2 days and i almost give up.

The dataframe I have is

```
tibble[,5] [364 x 5] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Week        : int [1:364] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ WeekStarting: chr [1:364] "1/3/2016" "1/3/2016" "1/3/2016" "1/3/2016" ...
 $ day         : chr [1:364] "Monday" "Tuesday" "Wednesday" "Thursday" ...
 $ max_temp    : num [1:364] 46.9 45 41 45 59 ...
 $ Date        : POSIXct[1:364], format: "2016-01-04" "2016-01-05" "2016-01-06" "2016-01-07" ...
```

What i am doing

```
df_weather_daily$Date <- parse_date_time(paste(2016, df_weather_daily$Week, df_weather_daily$day, 1, sep="/"),'Y/W/U')
```

The first week's dates are fine. Week starts 1/3/2016 and day is Monday so the date is 2016-01-04. When the week number is 2, the Date field repeats itself from 2016-01-04. so Dates basically loop from 03 to 09.

How can can I fix this to get dates populated for the whole year ? Thanks !

Comment: please provide a reprex look into dput

Comment: See here to provide a reproducible example <https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example>

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only have the following two pieces of date information: day of year and year then start by creating your `WeekStarting` variable:

#### 1)

Note: using `%U` assuming your week starts on *Sunday*. If it starts on Monday then use `%W` instead.

```
yr <- "2016"
df$WeekStarting <- as.Date(paste0(yr, sprintf("%02d", df$Week), "00"), "%Y%U%w")           

head(df$WeekStarting, 8)
[1] "2016-01-03" "2016-01-03" "2016-01-03" "2016-01-03" "2016-01-03" "2016-01-03"
[7] "2016-01-03" "2016-01-10"
```

If you already have `WeekStarting` in the format posted in your question then you can start here:

#### 2)

```
dow <- setNames(0:6, c("Sunday", 
                       "Monday", 
                       "Tuesday", 
                       "Wednesday", 
                       "Thursday", 
                       "Friday", 
                       "Saturday"))

# WeekStarting is character, like in your question
within(df, Date <- as.Date(WeekStarting, "%m/%d/%Y") + dow[day]) 

# If you started in Step 1
within(df, Date <- WeekStarting + dow[day])
```

**Output**

```
   Week       day WeekStarting       Date
1     1    Sunday   2016-01-03 2016-01-03
2     1    Monday   2016-01-03 2016-01-04
3     1   Tuesday   2016-01-03 2016-01-05
4     1 Wednesday   2016-01-03 2016-01-06
5     1  Thursday   2016-01-03 2016-01-07
6     1    Friday   2016-01-03 2016-01-08
7     1  Saturday   2016-01-03 2016-01-09
8     2    Sunday   2016-01-10 2016-01-10
9     2    Monday   2016-01-10 2016-01-11
10    2   Tuesday   2016-01-10 2016-01-12
11    2 Wednesday   2016-01-10 2016-01-13
12    2  Thursday   2016-01-10 2016-01-14
13    2    Friday   2016-01-10 2016-01-15
14    2  Saturday   2016-01-10 2016-01-16
15    3    Sunday   2016-01-17 2016-01-17
16    3    Monday   2016-01-17 2016-01-18
17    3   Tuesday   2016-01-17 2016-01-19
18    3 Wednesday   2016-01-17 2016-01-20
19    3  Thursday   2016-01-17 2016-01-21
20    3    Friday   2016-01-17 2016-01-22
21    3  Saturday   2016-01-17 2016-01-23
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Week = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), day = c("Sunday", 
"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", 
"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", 
"Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", 
"Friday", "Saturday")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-21L))
```